# How can I get todonotes in the left margin

Tags: margins, marginpar, double-sided, geometry, todonotes

I want to use the package todonotes. Standard, the package prints the todo's in the right margin, while I want to have them in the left margin. Funny is, that in the manual itself they are placed in the left margin, but no documentation is given how to do that.

How can I get my todonotes nicely in my left margin!

(I am using `\usepackage[left=3.7cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=4.2cm]{geometry}` as my margins, if that's relevant. Also, if somebody thinks another package with the same functionality is better, please suggest)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Add `\reversemarginpar` after loading the geometry and todonotes packages.  Note that as todonotes writes to the auxiliary file, you'll need to compile your source file at least twice to ensure that the lines it draws between the margin note and the connecting text are properly organised.

Answer (score 18):

I can't check it right now with the geometry package, but a manual says:

> 1.6.5 Todonotes wrongly placed in the margin

> When using some document classes or packages, the todonotes inserted in the page
> margin can be placed quite oddly. This is often caused by a wrong value of the
> `\marginparwidth` lenght. Try using the code below in your preamble to see if this
> cures the problem.

> `\setlength{\marginparwidth}{2cm}`

Perhaps try to redefine this after loading the geometry package.

**EDIT:**

From https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Footnotes_and_Margin_Notes#Margin_Notes : use command
`\reversemarginpar`

This operates on a `\marginpar` command, which is used by todonotes.

Comment: That I tried already, but it is not the problem. That command only is about the width of the box, not it's location. Also without the geometry package the todonotes are in the right margin.

Comment: +1 for `\reversemarginpar` because Geoffrey Jones beat you by only 20 seconds.