# Moving todo notes to other side of page

Tags: marginpar, todonotes

I am using the todo notes package, documentation of which can be found here.

The current document I am working on is in a book style format - in particular, there are wider margins on the left for odd pages, and on the right for even pages.

However, todo notes seems to have decided to alternate which side it will put notes by putting them on which ever side is **thinner**. This isn't actually an issue on the even pages, but on the odd pages it is cutting off most of the text.

There seems to be no right/left option in the documentation, does anyone know if I can do this manually. Preferably I would put all notes on the right, since this is probably by far the easiest working solution.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Without a MWE it's difficult to answer but try using `\reversemarginpar`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer and Andrew, so in making a MWE it transpires this is an issue with the ecsthesis class (linked at the end), not just book as I had assumed (book is the base class of ecsthesis). I will try to work out which part of ecsthesis causes this and then post the appropriate MWE, or a solution if one is obvious. Sorry for not giving a MWE initially!

Comment: Probably this does not help, but ... what about the inline option?

Comment: BTW, texdoc todonotes > see section 1.6.5 (page 9).

Comment: Another thing worth trying is `\usepackage{mparhack}`.

Comment: Old question, but one comment: The usual behaviour is for the outer margin to be wider, so odd pages should have a wider *right* margin, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42063/586.   By the way,  that class and template has something of a history, see https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion/blob/master/ourFamousThesisTemplate.md

Answer (score 1):

Try in your preamble

```
\reversemarginpar
```

But this only works for **all** notes. [Problem described here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141441/how-to-place-todonotes-in-left-and-right-margin).