# Write absolute pagenumber of a reference to a file by macro

Tags: write, zref

I want to write the absolute pagenumber of a reference to a file. therefore i cant use `\immediate\write`. The problem is now i think that `\write` expands its parameters when a page is finished, but then i of course get the same counter number for all invocations on that page. There my question is: How do i pass the counter value from the time of the expansion of the command to `\write`?

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{zref-savepos}
    \usepackage{zref-abspage}
    \usepackage{zref-user}

    \newcounter{acnt}

    \newwrite\tempfile
    \immediate\openout\tempfile=tmp.txt

    \makeatletter
    \newcommand\test{   
        \stepcounter{acnt}
        A \zsavepos{pos\arabic{acnt}}
        \write\tempfile{Nr \arabic{acnt} is on page \zref@extract{pos\arabic{acnt}}{abspage}}   
    }
    \makeatother

    \begin{document}

        \test
        \test
        \newpage
        \test
        \test
        \test

    \end{document}
```

And the output is:

```
    Nr 2 is on page 0
    Nr 2 is on page 0
    Nr 5 is on page 0
    Nr 5 is on page 0
    Nr 5 is on page 0
```

But it should be:

```
    Nr 1 is on page 1
    Nr 2 is on page 1
    Nr 3 is on page 2
    Nr 4 is on page 2
    Nr 5 is on page 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The label written by `\zsavepos` only stores the properties `posx` and `posy`. Therefore the value for `abspos` is undefined and the default `0` is used.
The reason for this is efficiency. If a label would store each kind of properties (lots of counter values, section titles, ...), the size of the `.aux` files and the memory imprint would be huge. Therefore `zref` allows and hopefully encourages label settings with the needed properties only.

Module `zref-savepos` maintains a property list `savepos` with properties `posx` and `posy`. This list can be extended:

```
\zref@addprops{savepos}{abspage}% global
\zref@localaddprops{savepos}{abspage}% local
```

The following example extends the list locally to avoid adding properties for `\zsavepos` labels, where they are not needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\usepackage{zref-abspage}
\usepackage{zref-user}

\newcounter{acnt}

\newwrite\tempfile
\immediate\openout\tempfile=tmp.txt

\makeatletter
\newcommand\test{
    \stepcounter{acnt}
    A %
    \begingroup
      \zref@localaddprops{savepos}{abspage}%
      \zsavepos{pos\arabic{acnt}}%
    \endgroup
    \immediate\write\tempfile{%
      Nr \arabic{acnt} is on page
      \zref@extract{pos\arabic{acnt}}{abspage}%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \test
    \test
    \newpage
    \test
    \test
    \test

\end{document}
```

The result `tmp.txt`:

```
Nr 1 is on page 1
Nr 2 is on page 1
Nr 3 is on page 2
Nr 4 is on page 2
Nr 5 is on page 2
```

The example uses `\immediate\write`, because the test file does not show
a reason for a deferred writing. Deferred writing is usually needed, if there are properties like page numbers, which are correct at shipout time. But the write command only writes the current counter value and a reference.