# Move changes-comment/remark boxes to the left

Tags: margins, changes

**tl;dr** Using the [changes package](https://ctan.org/pkg/changes?lang=en) - how can I move comment/remark boxes to the other side of the page?

Minimal (working) example (based on [PlosONE template](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/s/latex)):

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.85in,left=2.75in,footskip=0.75in]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\raggedright
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5cm}
\textwidth 5.25in 
\textheight 8.75in

\usepackage{changes}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
{\Large
\textbf\newline{Title of submission to PLOS journals}
}
\newline
\end{flushleft}

\section*{Abstract}
\added[remark={foo bar!}]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.} Curabitur eget porta erat. Morbi consectetur est vel gravida pretium. Suspendisse ut dui eu ante cursus gravida non sed sem. Nullam sapien tellus, commodo id velit id, eleifend volutpat quam. Phasellus mauris velit, dapibus finibus elementum vel, pulvinar non tellus. Nunc pellentesque pretium diam, quis maximus dolor faucibus id. Nunc convallis sodales ante, ut ullamcorper est egestas vitae. Nam sit amet enim ultrices, ultrices elit pulvinar, volutpat risus.
\comment{baz foo bar.}

\end{document}
```

[image: rendered image]

**extended description**

We currently in the process of writing a submission to a journal that requires [the PlosONE latex template](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/s/latex) to be used. In the past we relied heavily on annotations using the [changes package](https://ctan.org/pkg/changes?lang=en) to sync our collaborative writing process.

As you can see from the above screenshot, the PlosONE template is highly skewed to the right, leaving quite some space on the left side. However, when we use annotations including remarks and comments, the respective boxes are always rendered on the right. The right margin is quite small, though, which makes the content of the boxes mostly unreadable.

We would like to use the much bigger left margin to show those boxes. Any idea how to tell changes to render them on the left margin, so we can make use of that space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the fact that no mention of the `todonotes` package is made in the question, I would not point this question as a duplicate of [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5180/how-can-i-get-todonotes-in-the-left-margin), however as the `changes` package uses the `todonotes` package to handle comments the same solution works.

Add `\reversemarginpar` just after loading the `changes` package to get comments in the left margin.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.85in,left=2.75in,footskip=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\raggedright
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5cm}
\textwidth 5.25in 
\textheight 8.75in

\usepackage{changes}
\reversemarginpar

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
{\Large
\textbf\newline{Title of submission to PLOS journals}
}
\newline
\end{flushleft}

\section*{Abstract}
\added[comment={foo bar!}]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.}
\lipsum[1]
\comment{baz foo bar.}

\end{document}
```

[image]