# Fixing position and width of remarks in Changes package

Tags: changes

I am using the Changes package to track changes in a manuscript my supervisor and I are writing. I am unable to do three things:

1. Adjust the width of the remark text box. Either specify a box width or allow it to automatically use the remainder of the margin on the right.
2. Remove the remark number in the text box. I would only like it to name the one suggesting the edit and the comment itself, but move the remark number.
3. Make all boxes come to the right of the document.

In particular for problem 3, I tried the solution given here: [Move changes-comment/remark boxes to the left](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509967/move-changes-comment-remark-boxes-to-the-left), but seems to work only for one page. Over a multi-page document, the position of the comment box appears to alternate sides. If it possible to explicitly say "go right" to the comment box?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[authormarkupposition=left,
authormarkuptext=name]{changes}
\definechangesauthor[name={Daniel Wombosi}, color=blue]{Aut1}
\definechangesauthor[name={Mariam Wombosi}, color=orange]{Aut2}
\usepackage[alsoload=synchem,%
            range-phrase=--,%
            repeatunits=false%
            ]{siunitx}                                                  %For the ability to write SI units
\sisetup{range-units=single}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}
\sisetup{detect-all}

\reversemarginpar
\definechangesauthor[name={Reviewer 1}, color=orange]{Rev1}
\definechangesauthor[name={Authors}, color=blue]{Authors}

\begin{document}
Avatar: The Last Airbender, known as Avatar: The Legend of Aang in some regions, is an American animated television series produced by Nickelodeon Animation Studios. It was co-created by Michael Dante DiMartino and Bryan Konietzko, with \comment[id={Aut1}]{You did a good job! I loved Iroh very much.}{Aaron Ehasz} as head writer. It aired on Nickelodeon for three seasons, from February 2005 to July 2008.[2]     
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can provide a solution for your first two questions, the third does not appear in your example if you don't use `\reversemarginpar`, maybe you can provide another example showing the problem.

Question 1: set `\marginparwidth` to the desired width. But don't do that, rather adjust your page layout including the margins to a pleasing layout.

Question 2: use `\setcommentmarkup`, simplify the example to something you like.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[authormarkupposition=left,authormarkuptext=name]{changes}
\definechangesauthor[name={Daniel Wombosi}, color=blue]{Aut1}

% question 1
% don't do that, alter the geometry of your page layout accordingly
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{40mm}

% question 2
\setcommentmarkup{%
    \IfIsColored%
        {\colorlet{Changes@todocolor}{authorcolor}}%
        {\colorlet{Changes@todocolor}{black}}%
    \todo[color=Changes@todocolor!10, bordercolor=Changes@todocolor, linecolor=Changes@todocolor!70, nolist]{%
        \textbf{[#3]} #1%
    }%
}

% question 3: don't use reversemarginpar and all comments are on the right
%\reversemarginpar

\begin{document}
Avatar: The Last Airbender, known as Avatar: The Legend of Aang in some regions, is an American animated television series produced by Nickelodeon Animation Studios. It was co-created by Michael Dante DiMartino and Bryan Konietzko, with \comment[id={Aut1}]{You did a good job! I loved Iroh very much.}{Aaron Ehasz} as head writer. It aired on Nickelodeon for three seasons, from February 2005 to July 2008.[2]
\clearpage
Avatar: The Last Airbender, known as Avatar: The Legend of Aang in some regions, is an American animated television series produced by Nickelodeon Animation Studios. It was co-created by Michael Dante DiMartino and Bryan Konietzko, with \comment[id={Aut1}]{You did a good job! I loved Iroh very much.}{Aaron Ehasz} as head writer. It aired on Nickelodeon for three seasons, from February 2005 to July 2008.[2]
\end{document}
```